# Change the text in firebase federated login buttons

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to change the text in the social sign in buttons when using Firebase?

I would like to change the text from "Sign in with Google" to "Sign up with Google" as I am using firebase authentication to create accounts for my users during the sign up journey.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use fullLabel

```
{
    provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    fullLabel: 'Sign up with Facebook'
},
{
    provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    fullLabel: 'Sign up with Google'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but you can always create your customized button.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change them with **querySelectorAll** just running after loading the app in this way.  or 
folow this link : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

```
window.addEventListener('load', initApp);

setTimeout(function () {
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-provider-id="google.com"] >span')[1].innerText = 'Entrar con Google'
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-provider-id="facebook.com"] >span')[1].innerText = 'Entrar con Facebook'
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-provider-id="password"] >span')[1].innerText = 'Entrar con Email'
    }, 400)
```

Comment: I put this into the `uiShown` callback of the `uiConfig`